# Clip string inside of Array

Tags: c#, arrays, string

Lets say I have a String Array full of items such as:

```
string[] letters = new string[4] {"A1","B1","C1","D1"};
```

Later, I want to set the contents of a textbox to the first value in the array:

```
Letter.Content = letters[0];
```

Is there a way to 'clip' the number out of the String in the Array? For example, in my above code, currently the Letter textbox would be set to 'A1'. What I want however is to set it to just 'A'.

Comment: Or `letters[0].Substring(0,1)`

Comment: or use the `Letter.Content = letters[0].substring(0,1)`

Comment: Will the Array always follow the same format..? this is very important other wise what @TimSchmelter has provided will work

Comment: Yup, always the same format. So my question is pretty much answered. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on if the strings's length is always two and the digit is at the second position. Then it's simple:

```
Letter.Content = letters[0][0];
```

If you don't know the length but you want to take all letters from the left until there is a non-letter you could use `string.Concat` + LINQ:

```
Letter.Content = string.Concat(letters[0].TakeWhile(Char.IsLetter));
```

Answer (score 1):

or you could do it the old fashion way using `SubString` Method

```
Letter.Content = letters[0].Substring(0,1);
```